# Как сделать, чтобы меню переключалось через include?

Tags: меню, php, html

Как сделать, чтобы меню переключалось через include на php

Вот меню

```
<li>Новостройки</li>
<li>Нежилые помещения</li>
<li>Дома и коттеджи</li>
<li>Дачи</li>
<li>Земельные участки</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам необходимо поменять или создать с нуля - расширение вашего файла из html на php -  index.php

Например в данный момент так

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
       <li>Новостройки</li>
       <li>Нежилые помещения</li>
       <li>Дома и коттеджи</li>
       <li>Дачи</li>
       <li>Земельные участки</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

берем код меню

```
<ul>
   <li>Новостройки</li>
   <li>Нежилые помещения</li>
   <li>Дома и коттеджи</li>
   <li>Дачи</li>
   <li>Земельные участки</li>
</ul>
```

и сохраняем в новом файле также с расширением php например - menu.php

теперь файл index.php будет иметь следующий вид

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

более подробно - http://www.php.su/include()

Comment: Осталось только объяснить, зачем нужно голый HTML сохранять в файле с расширением php :-) Или что - `include('menu.html')` работать не будет?

Comment: будет - это как пример

Answer (score 1):

Вот так выглядит файл `menu.php`, который предлагает подключить [soledar10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13968/soledar10)

```
<?php
$itemId = isset($_GET['itemId']) ? $_GET['itemId'] : 0; // выбранный пункт меню
$menuItems = array( // все пункты меню
    1 => 'Новостройки',
    2 => 'Нежилые помещения',
);
echo '<ul>';
foreach($menuItems as $menuItemId => $menuItem) {
    echo '<li><a href="?itemId=', $menuItemId, '" ',
         ($menuItemId == $itemId ? 'class="active"':''), // если активный совпадает с текущим, то выделить его с помощью класса CSS
         '>', $menuItem, '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Проблема в формировании базовой ссылки в строке `<a href="?itemId=', $menuItemId, '">`: её тоже надо как-то передать в menu.php, но пользоваться глобальными переменными - это прошлый век

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял то:

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="?menu=menu1">меню1</a></li>
       <li><a href="?menu=menu2">меню2</a></li>
       <li><a href="?menu=menu3">меню3</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

ну и свитч

```
<?php

switch($_GET['menu']) {

case 'menu1':
include("menu1.php");
break;

case 'menu2':
include("menu2.php");
break;

case 'menu3':
include("menu3.php");
break;

}
?>
```